# How to iterate over csv rows to extract text from URLS

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, web-scraping

Below is an image of the dataset from where the text in the URLs in the `SECFNAME` column has to be extracted. The main link to the text data is `https://www.sec.gov/Archives/` + `URL` in the `SECFNAME` column.

[image]

I want to iterate over each row to get the text data from URL. Any help will me appreciated

Comment: I tried to get the data from the url mentioned using python requests, do you have permission to access that data? It throws an error 403 (Forbidden) when you try to get the file.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any for loop. You can try:

```
dataframe["full_urls"] =  "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/"+ dataframe["SECFNAME"]
print(dataframe)
```

Just change `dataframe` with your data frame's variable's name.

Comment: @KavitaKhatavkar if you provide your data as a csv file link, we can help you more. thanks